# Using routes in AngularJS to gather data

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have an single page app built on AngularJS which is configured using HTML5 routing. 
So I use:

```
http://www.example.com/products rather than http://www.example.com/#/products
```

I also have wildcard subdomains affiliates can use for example:

```
http://myaffiliate.example.com
```

And I gather data about myaffiliate from a firebase using this controller:

```
app.controller("ReplicatedController", function($scope, $firebaseObject) {

    var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
    var refSubdomain = parts.shift();

    var ref = new Firebase("https://example-firebase.firebaseio.com/" + refSubdomain);
    var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
    syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "coach");
});
```

This all works fine but in addition to using a wildcard subdomain I also need affiliates to be able to use urls. For example:

```
http://example.com/myaffiliate
```

Is it possible to do this, and how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need the $routeProvider service so you can send route parameters. Then you're able to do something like this.

```
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/:my_affiliate', {
        //other route details
    });
})

.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  console.log($routeParams.my_affiliate); // This will print affiliate
});
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks!