# how to use angular routing to nest 3 mvc razor models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor, angular-ui-router

I want to have a UsersAdmin view that has Account Registration, UserProfile class and a Identity Role class. I am using MVC5 with default Individual Authentication.
I am using ui-router for my routing. I have seen many examples using a viewmodel to pass multiple models to a single cshtml view. But I am needing a more complex setup. I created a mock up of what I am looking for. What is the best way to do this. 
[image: mockup]

Here is what my setup looks like

ui-routing

```
 // Default route
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Document');

    // Application Routes States
    $stateProvider
      .state('app', {
          abstract: true,
          controller: "CoreController",
          resolve: {
              _assets: Route.require('icons', 'toaster', 'animate')
          }
      })
      .state('app.document', {
          url: '/Document',
          templateUrl: Route.base('Document/Index'),
          resolve: {}
      })
      .state('app.register', {
          url: '/Register',
          templateUrl: Route.base('Account/Register'),
          resolve: {}
      }).state('app.applicationUser', {
          url: '/ApplicationUser',
          templateUrl: Route.base('ApplicationUsers/Index'),
          resolve: {}
      }).state('app.role', {
           url: '/Role',
           templateUrl: Route.base('Role/Index'),
           resolve: {}
     }).state('app.roleCreate', {
           url: '/RoleCreate',
          templateUrl: Route.base('Role/Create'),
          resolve: {}
     }).state('app.userProfile', {
         url: '/UserProfile',
         templateUrl: Route.base('UserProfiles/Index'),
         resolve: {}
     }).state('app.userProfileCreate', {
         url: '/UserProfileCreate',
         templateUrl: Route.base('UserProfiles/Create'),
         resolve: {}
     }).state('app.login', {
         url: '/Login',
         templateUrl: Route.base('Account/Login'),
         resolve: {}
     });
 }
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
 <div ui-view class="app-container" ng-controller="CoreController">@RenderBody()</div>
```

Navigation

```
 <li>
   <a ui-sref="app.userProfile" title="Layouts" ripple="">
      <em class="sidebar-item-icon icon-pie-graph"></em>
         <span>User Profile</span>
   </a>
 </li>
```

I have no issue using modals for the Create,Details,Edit views if that is a easier solution. However I do not know how to pass the selected Id with its properties to the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ui-router can help you achieve this  by using

a.

```
ui-sref='stateName({param: value, param: value})'
```

The parameterr object passed along with the state name can be accessed in the controller using  $stateParams

b. 
In your controller you could do something like

```
if ($stateParams.id != null) {
// service call goes here
}
```

c. You need to use named views 
Something like

```
$stateProvider
  .state('report', {
    views: {
      'filters': { ... templates and/or controllers ... },
      'tabledata': {},
      'graph': {},
    }
  })
```

where

> filters

and

> tabledate

are the named views.

ui-view has a decent example for it here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Btw , I would suggest you first figure out the panels which are dynamic ( i.e the ones whose content changes because of some kind of user interaction ) vs static ones ( they dont change once loaded)  . You should only be looking at ui-views to replace the dynamic parts , there is no point in making the app more complicated by putting everything in a child view . The states can become very confusing very quickly.

I use the ng-include directive to load the static views in the parent state and only define child states for portion of the views that change.

```
<div ng-include="'/MyStaticView'" ng-show="MyCondition == true "></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe that I answered your question to someone else. You want to gather information through the URL, right?

[Using routes in AngularJS to gather data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289957/using-routes-in-angularjs-to-gather-data/29290960#29290960)

Comment: Im trying to see how it can be done with ui-router instead of ngRoute. It's actually a nested, nested view situation because of my routing setup

Comment: @texas697 I don't have much experience with ui-router, but my guess would be http://URL/:foo